# create document in cloudant using post request

Tags: android, android-volley, cloudant

I am trying to create new document in cloudant database using post request i have attached my android code, please let me know what should be done to create document and insert two values inside the document, i have attached the code for which i am getting 403 as response.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String url = "https:bluemix.cloudant.com/databasename/documentname";

private String REV;

enter code here
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void postreq(View view) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //data in document
    map.put("_id", "123");
    map.put("value1", "1567");
    map.put("value2", "1545");

    JsonObjectRequest jar1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(map), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                REV = jsonObject.getString("rev");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Json Error Res: ", "" + error);
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String credentials = "abcd:XYZ";
                                   //key:Password
            String auth = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            // Log.e("qqqq", auth);
            params.put("Authorization", auth);
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("Accept","application/json");


            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue req = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    req.add(jar1);
}}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it's a typo in the question, but your URL looks malformed. you may want to confirm the URL. when creating a new document the URL to POST to should be in the form of `https://$ACCOUNT.cloudant.com/$DATABASE` (your URL contains an additional `/documentname`).

See https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#create

Comment: the URL used in program is correct i have just edited it, it is in form "https://XYZ(username)-bluemix.cloudant.com/databasename/documentname"

Comment: if you want to create a named document then you should be making a PUT request (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#update). for POST requests your URL should not contain the `/documentname` (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#create)